# Receive form data as POJO with Quarkus without annotations

Tags: forms, quarkus

I have a Java application based on Quarkus 3.2.3, where I would like to receive form data that was sent through a HTTP POST as a POJO with no annotations.

It seems that this always gives me a response with HTTP status code 415 (Unsupported Media Type).

I would like to avoid adding any annotations to the POJO holding the form data, for portability and compatibility with other frameworks.

To receive the form data, I have this POJO:

```
public class DummyForm {
  public String firstName;
  public String lastName;
}
```

This is the method that can receive the form data:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Path("dummyForm")
public String formResult(DummyForm dummyForm) {
  return "";
}
```

By default, placing a call with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` will result in a status code 415 (Unsupported Media Type).

By comparison - if I would send JSON instead, it seems to work well with the same POJO with no annotations with:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("dummyForm")
public String formResult(DummyForm dummyForm) {
  return "";
}
```

Is there any way to get this to work with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` form data as well?

For clarity, the POST request body would be something like: `firstName=John&lastName=Doe`

Comment: This link (https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#multipart) is the official guide about multipart support and all is well explained.

Comment: I see that can be used for cases with multipart data, but in this case I'm looking to send regular application/x-www-form-urlencoded data with just the form data to go into a POJO.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using resteasy-reactive, I think it should work if you add `@RestForm @PartType(APPLICATION_JSON) DummyForm form` to your method parameter.

See also [this link](https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#multipart)

Comment: Thanks, I think this could work if the incoming POST body would be a form where one of the form fields is called 'dummyForm' and its value is a JSON representation of a DummyForm, so: `firstName=Test1&dummyForm=%7B%22firstName%22%3A%20%22ABC%22%2C%20%22lastName%22%3A%20%22DEF%22%7D` where firstName is interpreted as ABC.
I'm looking for a way to parse this into a DummyForm though, where the input POST data would be: `firstName=Test1&lastName=Test2`.